# how to prove matrix addition is continuous under certain matric topology?

Tags: general-topology

let $A,B$ be $m \times n$ matrices .
$\|A\|$ := the square root of sum of (individual entry square)  (hope it's clear :P)
$d(A, B) = \|A − B\|$,
already proved that $d$ is a metric.

(1)now proved that matrix addition is continuous under this metric topology
$+ : M(m, n) \times M(m, n) \to M(m, n)$.
You may use the fact that addition on
$\mathbb{R}$ is continuous (this can be proven, e.g., using the  epsilon− δ definition).
(2) Prove that matrix multiplication
$× : M(m, n) \times M(n, r) \to M(m, r)$
is continuous under this metric topology. You may use the fact that addition
and multiplication on $\mathbb{R}$  are continuous (again, these can be proven, e.g., using
the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition).

Comment: And if you are interested enough , then how to show the space of m*n matrices is homeomorphic to R(mn) with the standard topology

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29 for the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\|(A+B)-(C+D)\| = \|(A-C)+(B-D)\| \le \|A-C\| + \|B-D\|$. Hence if $\|A-C\|, \|B-D\| < {1 \over 2} \epsilon$, then $\|(A+B)-(C+D)\| < \epsilon$.

$\|AB-CD\| = \|AB-CB+CB-CD\| \le \|AB-CB\|+\|CB-CD\|$. Now suppose $\|A\|,\|B\| < M$ and $\|A-C\|, \|B-D\| < \min(1,{1 \over 2(M+1)} \epsilon)$, then
$\|AB-CD\| \le \|B\| \|A-C\| + \|C\| \|B-D\| < \epsilon $.
(This uses the fact that the Frobenius norm is submultiplicative.)